# A better way to take screenshot in Galaxy S 2.2?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-s, screenshots

In Galaxy S with Froyo installed, you can take a screenshot of your phone by holding the back button and tapping the home button. However, this involves the back key, and a lot of application close when you press or hold the back button.

Is there a way to get around this? It's a nice addition, but there is no point really if the only thing you can take screenshot of is the main menu, the desktop, and some very few application that doesn't close when you hold the back button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See these other two, older questions, about how to take screenshots: [taking a screenshot of an android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/taking-a-screenshot-of-an-android-phone) and [Can I screenshot my HTC Legend without rooting it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/213/can-i-screenshot-my-htc-legend-without-rooting-it)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in an app, and push the <kbd>back</kbd> button, you'll back out of the app.

However, while holding the <kbd>back</kbd> button, open the app and then press the <kbd>home</kbd> button; then you'll have your screen shot of the app.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to hold the back button for a long time, and then press the home button.  When you hold the back button for a long time it doesn't close the application or take you back.  This works from inside applications and even when the screen is locked.

Just try pressing the back button long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Press the back button then the home screen button its kind of control then print screen on a desktop

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND A WAY! First things first, hold onto the home button, and DON'T LET GO. Then press the "back" button while still holding on to the home button. Place another finger on the "back" button. You should now have two fingers holding both the back and home button. With your other hand, lock the screen and turn it back on. After unlocking the screen, go into the message thread you want to copy, and then take your fingers off the home and back buttons. VOILA! The screen will capture the messages and you don't have to worry about backing out of it.